Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x1d Metaplex Core
Getting the error Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x1d. when trying to mint a Metaplex Core asset from a collection using anchor.
Message: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x1d. 
Logs: 
[
  "Program 6VVXJ3hHsXn8kFqCWRPT6VeigbGkcHkUZhhopritHdMi invoke [1]",
  "Program log: Instruction: MintAsset",
  "Program CoREENxT6tW1HoK8ypY1SxRMZTcVPm7R94rH4PZNhX7d invoke [2]",
  "Program log: Instruction: Create",
  "Program log: Cannot specify both an update authority and collection on an asset",
  "Program CoREENxT6tW1HoK8ypY1SxRMZTcVPm7R94rH4PZNhX7d consumed 4499 of 191248 compute units",
  "Program CoREENxT6tW1HoK8ypY1SxRMZTcVPm7R94rH4PZNhX7d failed: custom program error: 0x1d",
  "Program 6VVXJ3hHsXn8kFqCWRPT6VeigbGkcHkUZhhopritHdMi consumed 13251 of 200000 compute units",
  "Program 6VVXJ3hHsXn8kFqCWRPT6VeigbGkcHkUZhhopritHdMi failed: custom program error: 0x1d"
]. 
Catch the `SendTransactionError` and call `getLogs()` on it for full details.


Using the Metaplex single token(NFT) account layout, the update_authority field is a Rust Enum that can represent either of three things,

None - no update authority set making the asset a soulbound asset
Address(Pubkey) - single asset with the update authority public key Pubkey
 Collection(Pubkey) - this marks the asset as a collection asset with the public key of the collection in Pubkey

In my code I have both the update authority and collection present.

        CreateV1CpiBuilder::new(&ctx.accounts.core_program)
            .asset(&ctx.accounts.asset)
            .collection(Some(&ctx.accounts.collection))
            .authority(Some(&ctx.accounts.payer))
            .payer(&ctx.accounts.payer)
            .owner(Some(&ctx.accounts.payer))
            .update_authority(Some(&ctx.accounts.payer))
            .system_program(&ctx.accounts.system_program)
            .name(params.name)
            .uri(params.uri)
            .invoke()?;

You can't have both of these fields present and you have to chose either one or the other in the CPI instruction above. Getting rid of the .update_authority(Some(&ctx.accounts.payer))  method made the error go away.
ref: https://developers.metaplex.com/core/what-is-an-asset
